# Different Button in List view

Tags: java, android, listview

I have two ArrayList namely "one" and "two" ["two" is always a sub-set of "one"], And i have a list view which is populating by Arraylist "one". Now am checking condition that if element of "two" is present in "one", then set ImageButton in list view and if not the set Button in list view. 
Below is my `getView` method. Any help or keywords will be appreciated.

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
         //HERE HOW TO SWITCH TWO LAYOUTS.. 
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invite_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
        viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.childButton);
        Typeface typeFace= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
        viewHolder.name.setTypeface(typeFace);
        //      viewHolder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.invitebuttonbackground);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    final String temp = getItem(position);


   final String tempname = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.name.setText(tempname);
    viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (customListner != null) {
                customListner.onButtonClickListner(position, temp, tempname);

            }

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one thing you can do is

```
View convertView;
if (whatever condition) {
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invite_row, null);
} else {
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invite_row_two, null);
}
```

if you can post your layout , i will have clear undestanding of what you want to doing.

Comment: The condition is if list one contains element of list two then inflate invite row else inflate invite_row_two.  
But i want to check this for every entry, how to achieve this.

Comment: for eg you have List1 and list2 then check obj = list1.get(position) if(list2.contains(obj)){ //inflate layout1 } else { inflate layout2} and this will be checked for every element of list1 if you have passed list1 to adapter